# Angular Oauth2 OIDC - How to check if user is logged in?

Tags: angular, authentication, oauth-2.0, angular-oauth2-oidc

I am using Angular 11 with version 10 of augular-oauth-oidc

Is this the correct way to check whether the user is currently logged in?

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private oauthService: OAuthService,
    private router: Router,
  ) {

 .
 .
 .

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const identityClaim = this.oauthService.getIdentityClaims();
    return identityClaim && identityClaim['name'] ? true : false;
  }
```

I feel this is hacky... I am just checking whether the name field exists within identity?

How does this prevent a user from just modifying this variable in his console - apart from server sided checks upon api submission or something.

Does Angular route guard and interceptor do this job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> check whether the user is currently logged in?

Depends on whether you're looking for either:

- (A) is the user *authorized* to make API calls?
- (B) is the user *authenticated* and what do we know about their identity?

For (B) *authentication* looking at the identity claims is perfectly fine. For (A) *authorization* you typically do this:

```typescript
const isAuthorized = this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken();
```

This is because the identity claims are *only* useful inside the SPA, whereas the access token is typically a bearer token that gets sent to the API, which again does its own validation and checks of the token.

> How does this prevent a user from just modifying this variable in his console

This is inherent to browser applications. You cannot prevent the user (or a bad browser) from tampering with code that runs, well, in the browser. This is indeed why the server must do its own check when you send along an access token.

> Does Angular route guard and interceptor do this job?

Angular routes don't know anything about OAuth2/OIDC by default. You could have a peek at [my sample route guard](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/master/src/app/core/auth-guard-with-forced-login.service.ts) that does check for authentication, which indirectly just checks `hasValidAccessToken()`.

Interceptors on their own also don't know about OAuth2/OIDC, but if [you configure `resourceServer`](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/1c928b50e60c0d259c54704bc9d00d46fdf1f2d8/src/app/core/auth-module-config.ts#L4-L7) in the library's `OAuthModuleConfig` a default interceptor gets registered from the library, which will send the access token along to all requests to a specific set of APIs.